# How to backup and restore all partitions including /boot/efi and swap

Tags: uefi, backup

I'm running Ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS.

I have two drives: sda and sdb with following partitions:

sda             111.8G
├─sda1 vfat       619M /boot/efi
├─sda2 swap       954M [SWAP]
└─sda3 ext4     110.3G /home
sdb             931.5G
└─sdb1 ext4     931.5G /

As you can see, I have 619M efi system partition, 954M swap, 110.3G /home, and finally 931.5G /.

If I want to backup everything including **all** partitions which tool should I use? Because, if you restore it to a new PC and omit the efi system partition /boot/efi, for example, it won't boot.

Comment: see clonezilla.org for opensource solution

Comment: I prefer Gnome-Disks. It can create an Image or restore an image from any Ubuntu machine or from any Ubuntu Live USB without downloading anything. It can clone the whole disk including bootloader or clone just the partitions. The image file can also be restored from Windows or Linux using common tools such as Etcher, Rufus, Win32DiskImager, mkusb, dd and Startup Disk Creator.

Comment: If UEFI, it may not boot anyway. You will not have 'ubuntu' entry, but it may boot from the fallback or hard drive boot entry at /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Often better with new drive, just to reinstall grub to have all parameters correct. I do separately backup ESP, but do not really expect to ever use it. No need to backup swap, it is just unformatted space. New installs now use swap file anyway. Typically new install. restore /home & list of installed apps is all you need. If server apps you need those folders in / and may want some settings in /etc if you edited those.